# Sufficient conditions for signed measures

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{A}$) be a measure space.

> An application $\nu\colon \mathcal{A}\to [-\infty, +\infty]$ is called **signed measure** on $\mathcal{A}$ if:
>
> - $\nu(\emptyset)=0$;
> - $\nu$ takes on at most one of the values $\pm \infty$;
> - for all sequence $\{E_n\}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ of disjoint sets results: $$\nu\left (\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu(E_n).$$

Suppose that we have an application $\mu\colon\mathcal{A}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $\mu(\emptyset)=0$;
2. $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(E_k)$$ for all finite family $\{E_1,\dots, E_n\}$ of disjoint sets;
3. $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(E_n)$$ for all increasing sequence $\{E_n\}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$.

> Can I coclude that $\mu$ is a signed measure? The first two properties are evidently satisfied. What I can't see is the last property.

Comment: *Hint.* Let $F_n:=\bigcup_{k=1}^nE_k$. Then
$$
\mu\!\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right)=\mu\!\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n\right)
\stackrel{(3)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(F_n)
=\ldots$$
Can you continue?

Comment: @nejimban Yes, thanks!